# Android: cannot resolve symbol "setImageResource"

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am trying to change the image for an ImageButton in my Java code, but I keep getting an error message "cannot resolve symbol "setImageResource".

The ImageButton is defined in my XML as follow:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_ir2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

And in my Java code:

```
            final View vz=findViewById(R.id.button_ir2);
            ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton)vz;
            aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
```

I think I am typecasting this correctly, but maybe not. Spent almost a day on this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you try directly ``ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ir2);``and forget ``vz``?

Comment: wouldn't help cause that's technically the same thing

Comment: The purpose of the code in Java is to change the image. In the XML, i set the image to img1, but after the application launches, I want to change the image to img2.

Comment: Fred: Same thing, I have tried all combos (I started off without defining vz). This is driving me nuts. Also, this is for Android Wear (I don't think that should matter)

Comment: SOLVED! But I don't know why. I deleted the project, re-populated from my git repository, copied the pasted the code above again, and it works! I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your code, so probably you don't have the `android.jar` file correctly set, or you have an error in your `res` folder.

go to project-properties-android. and set any other android version and check again.

Comment: I El, I tried a couple of older versions, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the `View` as final. You can not assign or modify that view.

Simplest solution could be:

```
ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ir2);
aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
```

Make sure the drawable img2 is in a correct format (.png).

Comment: Hi Mohammad. I tried this, same problem "cannot resolve symbol setImageResource"

Comment: Then the problem is in your image. Its awkward but sometime Android Studio messed up with image format. Did you renamed your image file from jpg to png or something?